# Why does my script not make new lines using keyup?

Tags: javascript, textarea, onkeyup

I'm coding a script for my forum which generates a preview of the given string.

Here is my js code

```
function MakePreview() {
var getText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
document.getElementById('outputText').innerHTML = getText;}
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<article>
    <h2>What are you doing?</h2>
    <textarea id="inputText" onkeyup="MakePreview()"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Hello"/>
</article>
<article>
    <p id="outputText"></p>
</article>
```

Furthermore I have an textarea for the input and an paragraph for the output. But the output does not make a new line like textareas does.

Usually a paragraph makes automatically new lines when the string is longer than the width of the given content.

Does someone have a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery because I first want to train my primary js skills

Comment: where is paragraph in your HTML?

Comment: onkeyup will trigger if any key is pressed and up.It is a bad idea of course

Comment: i pasted the wrong code without the paragraph. Here's the code: <p id="outputText"></p>

Comment: So, the `#outputText` is a `p` element instead of `textarea`? Please fix the code in the question too.

Comment: True, i tried to correct it but im just a dummy On this forum and didnt know how to edit your post but instead i posted a better description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if it's possible to achieve exactly what you want (due to the different font size and family), but this snippet is very close to it.

```js
function makePreview() {
    var text = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    document.getElementById('outputText').innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 150px;
}
.wrapper textarea {
    width: 100%;
} 
#outputText {
    position: relative;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: break-all;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <textarea id="inputText" oninput="makePreview()"></textarea>
    <p id="outputText"></p>
</div>
```

The idea is to wrap both the `textarea` and the `p` within a same parent to get their widths to match. `word-break: break-all` and `white-space: pre-wrap` "copies" the automatic text wrapping and entered new-lines within `textarea` to the `p` element.

However, the text might be cutted in a different place, depending on the used font family and size. You could get a better match if you'd use the same font in both elements.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you helped. this worked not for 100%, only when you use space and enter it will make new lines. If you make just only a paragraph it will make new lines when the width of the paragraph is shorter than the text, you get it?

Comment: @theMaster If I've understood your comment correctly, I've just fixed the issue in the code (added `word-break` property to `#outputText` rule).

Comment: Exactly! That's the solution! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: If it's a short word at the end of the line it will also be spread over 2 lines ...  How to solve that?

Comment: @JeroenJK Probably that can't be solved with this CSS. Words are cut arbitrarily because of `word-break: break-all`. On the other hand, if you'll omit the property, long words wouldn't be wrapped at all. Like I've said, this is just close to, but not exactly what OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct paragraph to respect new lines characters (and other whitespaces like tabs, spaces, etc.) by setting its [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property to `pre`:

```js
function MakePreview() {
    var getText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    document.getElementById('outputText').innerHTML = getText;
}
```

```css
#outputText {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="inputText" onkeyup="MakePreview()" rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
<p id="outputText"></p>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. That example in code snippet is something what I also used, but try it yourself by typing infinite characters in a row. You'll see my problem. Do you have the solution?

Comment: You want text to wrap the same it wraps in textarea? In this case you will need to set width of the paragraph to be the same as textarea.

Comment: Yes like you described I want to wrap the same it wraps in textarea. I also set the width of the paragraph the same as the textarea, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In html multiple whitespaces are replaced by single space so if you want to preview in paragraph you need to replace newlines with `<br/>`

```
function MakePreview() {
    var getText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    document.getElementById('outputParagraph').innerHTML = getText.replace('\n', '<br/>');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, want I want is that the paragraph automatically make a new line like the way you type in flat text. It worked for 50%, only when I pressed enter it makes a new line

Answer (score 0):

Use `wrap="hard"` on your textArea. It will help for new line if the length is more the textArea size.
For fixed row and column you can use `rows="2" cols="20"` in textarea.